# onBackPressed() method not working properly in android

Tags: android, exception, visibility

I m doing something like that.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        homeTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.rel_HomeLayout);
        reviewLayout = findViewById(R.id.scroll_ReviewLayout);

        if (reviewLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

        }
    }
```

but its raising the below Exceptions (while i m pressing the backKey)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and

```
my.package.name.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:303)
```

here is my XML file which does not contains this reviewLayout and reviewLayout.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rel_ScreenFirst"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/top_header_gradient"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_Register"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Login/Register"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Shia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_islamicLibrary"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Shia"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_islamicLibrary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_Shia"
                android:text="IslamicLibrary"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_dotCom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt_islamicLibrary"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_islamicLibrary"
                android:text=".com"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Rel_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rel_ScreenFirst"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_header"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnrLanguage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" >
            </Spinner>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spnrBrowseBy"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spnrLanguage" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditTxt_Search"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Search Here..."
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_GO"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:text="GO" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnrBrowseBy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Browse By" >
            </Spinner>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel_01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Rel_Spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

yes that's right, its not present in the content layout. how can I get reference of this view. while the actual view exits in my Home.java file.. and i m doing all this code in the Main.java file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the View that you have set  does not have R.id.scroll_ReviewLayout . So check whether it is present in the layout xml or add a null check

```
if (reviewLayout != null && reviewLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: @MohdMufiz it will first check null, if it is not null only then will the next statement be processed , otherwise the next statement will never be called

Comment: f (reviewLayout != null && reviewLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) { // reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); Log.i("If reviewLayout", reviewLayout + ""); } else { Log.i("Else reviewLayout", reviewLayout + ""); }
 
I tried this and log prints the "Else reviewLayout" => Null

Comment: Actullay i have to make hide a view on the backKey Press event. so how can i achive it?

Comment: @QadirHussain You should post the layout xml

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure. But try below changes

```
homeTabLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_HomeLayout); //(Relativelayout) is object of rel_HomeLayout. So ,use name of rel_HomeLayout control


 reviewLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroll_ReviewLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a log below the line

```
reviewLayout = findViewById(R.id.scroll_ReviewLayout);
```

and see if reviewLayout is null

```
 Log.i("Log","reviewLayout " + reviewLayout);
```

Comment: if (reviewLayout != null
    && reviewLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
   // reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   Log.i("If reviewLayout", reviewLayout + "");
  } else {
   Log.i("Else reviewLayout", reviewLayout + "");
  }

Comment: So you messed up the connection between layout and code somewhere. You can 1) crosscheck you have given `scroll_ReviewLayout` as the id in the layout file. 2) make sure this layout in question is presented in the content layout you set as setContentView.

Comment: Actullay i have to make hide a view on the backKey Press event. so how can i achive it?

Comment: To hide (or doing anything else) you must first reference the view. But your connection is not seemed to be correct. You will have to get reviewLayout reference, not null, to work with it..

Comment: yes that's right, its not present in the content layout. how can I get reference of this view. while the actual view exits in my Home.java file.. and i m doing all this code in the Main.java file.

Comment: Best method will be to create a public function in home.java file (where you can access the view) and call this function from Main.java..

Comment: Also, I do think you should work on your project structure. It is not good when you reference layout allover the place in a project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19819/discussion-between-qadir-hussain-and-krishnabhadra)